# How to connect to a collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, collections, orm, database-connection

I want to use the collections as DBs!  That is, make a connection from node.js where you can use a collection as a normal database?

The purpose of this is that I'm going to create two totally different apps, with different collections and documents, but there are data that I need to relate between the two apps. And if the two apps are using the same database, it would be much easier for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. MongoDB doesnt do that, what can you do is something like give a prefix name to your collections, "projectA_Users , projectB_Users" and to relate data use the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) Aggregate operator to get your relationship. I see something like that on FireBase that you can create a collection inside a document and use find, update, remove on it [(here)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model?hl=en-us#hierarchical-data)